# Embarrassingly parallel machine learning algorithms

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistical-learning

What learning algorithms are "embarrassingly parallel?"  I'll kick it off with the obvious example from the [foreach documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf):

```
rf <- foreach(ntree = rep(250, 4), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar%
 randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree)
```

What else is out there that can be easily parallelized with `foreach`?

Comment: This paper might be relevant given that foreach is effectively a map-reduce operation: http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips19/NIPS2006_0725.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bagging is embarrassingly parallel](http://viksalgorithms.blogspot.com/2012/01/build-your-own-bagging-function-in-r.html):

```
bagging<-function(training,testing,length_divisor=4,iterations=1000)
{
predictions<-foreach(m=1:iterations,.combine=cbind) %do% {
training_positions <- sample(nrow(training), size=floor((nrow(training)/length_divisor)))
train_pos<-1:nrow(training) %in% training_positions
lm_fit<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3,data=training[train_pos,])
predict(lm_fit,newdata=testing)
}
rowMeans(predictions)
}
```

[Code from R, Ruby, and Finance](http://viksalgorithms.blogspot.com/2012/01/build-your-own-bagging-function-in-r.html)